# Why I need to alloc memory to a string instead of using only a pointer always?

Tags: c, memory

I am wondering why I need to alloc memory sometimes, to get an array with n size, but why I cannot instead of that using a pointer!

Look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "debug.h"
#include "memory.h"

char *getbuffer();

int main(void)
{

    char *line;

    line = getbuffer();
    printf("First Char: %c\n", line[0]);
    line[0] = 'g';
    printf("Writed: %c\n", line[0]);

    return 0;
}

char *getbuffer()
{
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("String: ");
    getline(&line, &len, stdin);

    return line;
}
```

The above code works, And I dont to do something like this, but I think its not correct using only a pointer, instead of alloc memory, but I dont know why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "debug.h"
#include "memory.h"

char *getbuffer();

int main(void)
{

    char *line;
    char *buffer;

    line = getbuffer();
    printf("Foi isto que escrevi: %s\n", line);
    buffer = malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffer, line);
    printf("Foi isto que escrevi: %c\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("Tamanho Buffer: %ld\n", strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}

char *getbuffer()
{
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("String: ");
    getline(&line, &len, stdin);

    return line;
}
```

So I am wondering, why I need to sometimes allocate memory to get the string or to save a string on an array instead of using always a pointer.

Comment: `getline` allocates memory internally, probably by calling `malloc`, and assigns that pointer into the out param `&line`.

Comment: `getline()` allocates memory for you, if necesssary.

Comment: @ForceBru I dont know, I just declare it like that, and send it to getline and I get the line, and I can acess to every char, so I am wondering why I need to alloc memory and not use always only a pointer

Comment: @WeatherVane, huh, nice, didn't know that

Comment: @Alexander Ah, so the getline, does the malloc or realloc?

Comment: @ForceBru you can provide the buffer and its size, if you already have memory allocated. That's why you pass the *address* of the buffer pointer, and of its length.

Comment: @ForceBru Oh, so I am wondering if getline cant alloc enough memory where do I get the allocation error?

Comment: @GonçaloBastos Well it must. Look at the values in the debugger. Before the call to `getline`, the value of `char *line` will be whatever junk was on the stack at the time `getbuffer()`'s stackframe was allocated. After the call, it'll point to a region of memory containing real string contents terminated with a `'\0'`. That's not an accident, it *must* be doing some kind of allocation internally, or none of that would work.

Comment: Please see the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: OT: `buffer = malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));` should be `buffer = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);`

Comment: The OPs `getbuffer()` code is out of compliance with `getline` anyway. The pointer sent by address to `getline` must either contain NULL or a valid address returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, *regardless* of the value sent by address for the size. The fix is simple enough (`char *line = NULL:`) , but as-written the code is a gamble. The  chosen conjunction, "If \*lineptr is set to NULL **and** \*n is set 0 before the call,..." is no accident. The OPs code honors only half of that recipe. That the return value of `getline` is completely ignored isn't doing any favors either.

Comment: "if getline cant alloc enough memory where do I get the allocation error?" -- the return value of `getline` (which you ignore).  It will return -1 (with errno set to ENOMEM) if there's a memory allocation problem.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I already read the man and saw that but thanks anyways